# Looking for an Ajax or PHP trick to detect if they have Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am looking for some kind of trick to determine if a user has javascript... I figure I could do it somehow by sending a ajax request at the top of a page, and in that ajax request, set a session variable, and then somehow reload the page, and see of it was set...

Is there any tricks like this around in PHP/AJAX?

Comment: what is your ultimate goal here? Do you just want to know on the client side (for CSS or something) or on the server side? Either way, this is a dupe...

Comment: A number of answers have attempted to actually answer this, but you are probably asking the wrong question. Build on stuff that works: http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to redirect if javaScript is disabled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489376/how-to-redirect-if-javascript-is-disabled)

Answer (score 7):

What you can do is add code like this (no AJAX needed):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;URL=/?nojs" />
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location.href="/?js";
</script>
```

However, **you should not do that**. Instead, serve the basic website every time, and decorate it with a `script` element that loads all the JavaScript that modifies and adds dynamic content.

Comment: Damnit. I was just about to post the same thing. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can always use the noscript tags:

```
<noscript>
<input type="hidden" name="has_javascript" value="false">
</noscript>
```

and detect that on the server.

Answer (score 0):

aif is mistaken. 
Even if JS is disabled, if your browser supports JS it is listed as javascript=1.

Answer (score -2):

you could use a very simple tip:

```
<script>document.location="/index2.php";</script>
<p>You need javascript for an improved navigation!</p>
```

where the current page (which I assume is index.php) is only used to redirect the visitor to the actual index page : index2.php

or use [get_browser](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) which provides a field for javascript. I tested it with firefox (disabling js and not) and it worked pretty fine for me.

Comment: you should set `window.location.href` instead of `document.location`

Answer (score -4):

```
$results = get_browser();
if ($results["javascript"] == 1) {
echo "You have javascript";
}
```

([source](http://bytes.com/groups/php/541838-how-do-i-check-if-javascript-enabled-php))

Comment: I believe that only tells you whether the user's browser is *capable* of Javascript, not whether it's actually been enabled or disabled.