# Deciding whether javascript is disabled/enabled and execute a server side code

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, browser

I've an aspx page which loads several images after detecting client's screen size. Here is how I do this:
In jquery code, I first detect user screen size, then depending on the size, I do some calculations to decide the number of images to be fetched from database. Then with the use of jquery ajax, I call up a web service which returns json response. Code picks up json and creates page.

Now, if user has disabled javascript, this approach doesn't work. Now I have to create page using c# code on code behind. The problem is, I can't detect if javascript is disabled from code behind (I think this is not possible). I do not want to display a button at the top says something "Javascript is disable in your browser. Please click here to display this page". I can put this button in noscript tags. But I do not want user have to click a button before seeing images on page.

What I want, if javascript is disabled, system should detect it and immediately run a function from code behind. (IN this case page size would be fixed and won't vary according to user screen) I can not use a hidden field or cookie to detect it since they both will need a postback before detecting javascript is diabled. (We know that js code can't run before any page life-cycle event).

Well I don't have much hope that my problem could be resolved, but still I want to give it a try. May be someone already have a solution. It would be extremely helpful if you could give your views or suggestion to change/update logic.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks and Regards
Praveen

Comment: stop worrying about users with disabled javascript, it was a problem before when it was new, now javascript is a must to surf over the web. Summary: It's their problem that they have disabled it.

Comment: @Rawling, this is not a duplicate of that post, since I've surfed too much before asking. I never wanted a redirect solution. I thought, there could be a clean way. I also wrote- "Well I don't have much hope that my problem could be resolved". Anyways thanks.

Comment: You're going to need a redirect in there somewhere. The server doesn't know whether the client supports Javascript; you'll need to get the client to tell the server at some point after the page is sent i.e. redirect. The linked question provides a way to automatically redirect to a no-code version of the page; one of the answers provides a way to automatically recdirect to a code-enabled version.

Answer (score 1):

1.) Use JavaScript to set a cookie, and then test for that cookie using server-side scripting upon subsequent page views; deliver content appropriately.

**[How to detect if JavaScript is disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled)**

2.) You can use **`<noscript>` tag**.

The **`<noscript>` tag**: can be used to provide an alternate content for users that have disabled scripts in their browser or have a browser that doesn’t support client-side scripting.

```
<noscript>
    ....
</noscript>
```

3.) **[Detect if JavaScript is enabled in ASPX](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23831/Detect-if-JavaScript-is-enabled-in-ASPX)**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["JSChecked"] == null)
    //JSChecked -indicates if it tried to run the javascript version
    {
        // prevent infinite loop
        Session["JSChecked"] = "Checked";
        string path = Request.Url + "?JScript=1";
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "redirect", 
          "window.location.href='" + path + "';", true);
    }
    if (Request.QueryString["JScript"] == null)
        Response.Write("JavaScript is not enabled.");
    else
        Response.Write("JavaScript is enabled.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I already said I can't use cookies since they will be set by javascript which executes after page loads. redirects would not suit my situation. I was looking for a solution and I come to know what I was thinking is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Make default version without javascript and redirect to javascript version if javascript enabled. [How to redirect if javaScript is disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2489376/1735047)

Comment: Thanks for responding. Redirects would not suit my situation. I was looking for a solution and I come to know what I was thinking is not possible.