# If js disabled, how to show php-generated site?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a full js/jquery based WebSite!

Today i become an E-mail, "i have js disabled..." 
How can i check at start, if js is disabled, so locate from index.html to some.php?

for google robot too!

Thx in ahead!

Comment: You simply can't check. There is a `<noscript>` HTML tag though, which you could use to inform the user and show a link to some.php.

Comment: This might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489376/how-to-redirect-if-javascript-is-disabled

Comment: @jmbertucci post it pls as answer, i vote it ;)

Comment: @Akdes Thanks for the support but this is a duplicate question and so it should get closed as such.  Glad it helped, Best of luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, php has no way of checking if Javascript is disabled or not. But what you could is starting the page on a index.php and putting in a js script that redirects you to the 'real' website. so if javascript is disabled you wont be redirected and you stay on the php page and otherwise you go to the js website