# A way to detect if JavaScript is disabled without using noscript?

Tags: javascript, html, popup, noscript

I was messing around with creating a popup message for if JavaScript is disabled. I'm using html, css, and bootstrap inside my project.  I was wondering if there a way to detect if the html class inside my project was still "no-js"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Comment: How can you pop up a message when JavaScript is disabled? You should probably just rely on the `<noscript>` tag or style your CSS based off a class that JavaScript removes if it is enabled.

Comment: You can create a popup box using html5 and css3.  For an example of this you can go to [link](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/).

Comment: However the problem I'm running into is that it just prints the tags and everything else as just text whenever it's inside noscript.

Comment: Please take a look this answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489376/how-to-redirect-if-javascript-is-disabled

Answer (score 0):

Use `< noscript >`. If you aren't getting the results you want, your markup inside `< noscript >` probably isn't correct.

Otherwise, if you want to know if a browser has disabled JS, an easy way would be to add an element to your `< header >`, styled with a class that makes a pretty alert. Then, the first line of your JS would hide that element. The opposite way would be to select the element with CSS and display the alert, and then your first line of JS would be to hide the element.