# Is it possible to redirect a page without using javascript after php header?

Tags: php, html

I searched and didn't find an answer without javascript.

I need to somehow redirect the user to other page without using javascript and after i already set the header... is it possible?

Comment: only possibility is to make user click a button, nothing else automatic.

Comment: I searched in Google for "redirect without javascript" and got [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489376/how-to-redirect-if-javascript-is-disabled) as a first result...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can output [a meta refresh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh).

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/">
```

While it *technically* belongs only in the `<head>`, I tested several browsers and they all appear to process it even in the `<body>`.

Comment: is there any problem using this instead of javascript i mean any cons?

Comment: @ThiagoSabin Needing to do it this way is a bit of a sign that something's iffy in your application. Any modern framework like Laravel does all the logic in the controller, then decides whether to redirect, display a view, etc. before outputting anything to the browser. A meta refresh isn't seen by search engines like a HTTP redirect is, too.